# How to calculate the previous row and show in the current row of the table?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am fetching some data from the table using codeigniter

My table picture
[image]
This is my  table that i have fetched from the table.in this i have show the balance column in first row as 10 and next row as 35 how i calculate this using java script or php itself.

My code:

```
<table class="table datatable-button-html5-basic">
    <thead>
    <tr><h6>         
        <th class="col-sm">Bill No</th>
        <th class="col-sm" >Date</th>
        <th class="col-sm" >Particulars</th>
        <th class="col-sm" >Op.Stock</th>
        <th class="col-sm-7">Pur/Prod</th>
        <th class="col-sm" >Sales/Cons</th>
        <th class="col-sm" >Balance</th>        

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>
<tr>
     <?php $total = 0;
          $total += $row['qty'];  ?>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row['orderno'];?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row['orderdate'];?></td>
        <td >PRODUCTION</td>
        <td></td>       
        <td dir="rtl"><?php echo $row['qty'];?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo "$total" ;?></td>

</tr><?php endforeach ?>
<tr><?php foreach ($query1 as $row1): ?>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row1['billno'];?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row1['billdate'];?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row1['accName'];?></td>
        <td></td>       
        <td></td>
        <td dir="rtl"><?php echo $row1['salesqty'];?></td>
        <td></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

This is my table code. 
My another sample table: [image]

Comment: store balance column in one variable and increase it and display as total

Comment: i have done it but it doesn't give result

Comment: why there is two foreach ?

Comment: i am fetching from two table one from "order_item" and another from "sales_item" both doesn't have another common rows

Comment: first two rows should be add then next rows should be subract from that value

Comment: define your `$total = 0;` outside` foreach`, otherwise it set 0 on every loop

Comment: see my another picture for example

Comment: that i have set 0 value

Comment: you mean you want to sum all for different like sales and purchase ?

Comment: see my another picture you will get some idea

Comment: you need some of Balance column right ?

Comment: yes correct how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `$balance` before `foreach`, and sum as `$balance += $total;` every row of balance column.

```
 <table class="table datatable-button-html5-basic">
        <thead>
        <tr><h6>         
            <th class="col-sm">Bill No</th>
            <th class="col-sm" >Date</th>
            <th class="col-sm" >Particulars</th>
            <th class="col-sm" >Op.Stock</th>
            <th class="col-sm-7">Pur/Prod</th>
            <th class="col-sm" >Sales/Cons</th>
            <th class="col-sm" >Balance</th>        

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php

$balance = 0;
 foreach ($query as $row): ?>
    <tr>
         <?php $total = 0;
              $total += $row['qty']; 
             $balance += $total;
 ?>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row['orderno'];?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row['orderdate'];?></td>
            <td >PRODUCTION</td>
            <td></td>       
            <td dir="rtl"><?php echo $row['qty'];?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo "$total" ;?></td>

    </tr><?php endforeach ?>
    <tr><?php foreach ($query1 as $row1): ?>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row1['billno'];?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row1['billdate'];?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row1['accName'];?></td>
            <td></td>       
            <td></td>
            <td dir="rtl"><?php echo $row1['salesqty'];?></td>
            <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: you can use same for your other foreach, variable already defined so just us $balance += your balance variable

Comment: this $balance variable can be used to another one

Comment: you can add or substract from it whenever you want

Comment: how i subract the value by using it

Comment: use - instead of +

Comment: <?php $bal = 0;
foreach ($query1 as $row1): ?>
  <?php $tot = 0;
         $tot = $balance; 
             $bal = $tot - $row1['salesqty'];
 ?>